# Loading Plugins (DLLs) on-the-fly

Tags: d

Is there a way to dynamically load and call functions from DLLs dynamically in D? I'd like my program to be able to load plugins at startup and perhaps on-the-fly as well.

Comment: Yes. Here's a quick reference: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/dll.html

Comment: That's what I was afraid of...basically we're stuck with using the C method of getting the proc address and going from there. Not terrible I assume, since I can wrap all my plugin objects up into a "master factory", but not optimal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on how dynamic you want to get. If you want to dynamically load a dll and run some predefined functions, there is a very nice wrapper by Wei Li [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/A_Simple_DLL_Wrapper_6595.html#N6612). Thanks to the power of templates, it allows you to do things like these:

```
// define functions
alias Symbol!("MessageBoxW", int function(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT)) mbw;
alias Symbol!("MessageBoxA", int function(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)) mba;
// load dll
auto dll = new Module!("User32.dll", mbw, mba);
// call functions
dll.MessageBoxW(null, "Hello! DLL! ", "Hello from MessageBoxW", MB_OK);
dll.MessageBoxA(null, "Hello! DLL! ", "Hello from MessageBoxA", MB_OK);
```

The code is D1. For D2, you have to replace `char[]` with `string`, use `toStringz()` and possibly remove `scope`. **Edit:** [my D2 port](https://bitbucket.org/stephan/dunicode/src/tip/testperf/dllloader.d) of this code might be useful to others finding this question.

Comment: I wish I had more mod +1 points. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Timothy: Glad it helped. To me, the code is a good example how much you can achieve with a couple of lines of code using templates and mixins. It almost feels like Python.

Comment: I realize this is a few months old, but thanks a ton for the D 2.0 update! I also wish I had more upvotes to hand out!

Comment: @Mark: thanks for reminding me that I have to fix a bug in the unit tests of this code :-). I will do so on Monday when I am back in the office (and in front of a Windows box). So you might want to check back on Tuesday.

Comment: @stephan: Thanks for the heads up, I'll do so! I'm still trying to to figure it out (not exactly sure how to cast a string to a LPC(W)STR), but it looks very helpful!

Comment: @Mark: There is a function `toStringz` (http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_string.html#toStringz) that actually converts to zero-terminated `(immutable) char*` which is more or less `LPCSTR`. Note that string-literals (contrary to `string`s and the rest) are actually zero-terminated in D (that's why my example `user32.MessageBoxA(null, "Hello", "MessageBoxA", 0);` works). But for general strings, you have to use `toStringz` or roll your own conversion. This might be helpful: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/cppstrings.html

Comment: Link is dead, and I really need this. Could you please re-post your D2 port? I'm having trouble doing it myself. The error messages aren't very descriptive. This is about where [I've gotten](https://hastebin.com/ipinazonan.d) but if I change any of the character arrays to strings I get errors abounds.

Comment: Too late to edit my comment. Bitbucket appears to just have screwed up. I copied your code but now I'm getting `Error: need this for name of type const(string)` on lines 239 and 240, as well as errors instantiating the mixin on 156.

Comment: @spikespaz: apologies, I cannot help here. I haven't written D code in years and assume that the language spec has changed since writing this piece of code. I'd also assume there is a better solution by now. You might either ask a question on SO or on one of the [D forums](https://forum.dlang.org/). In the past, both have been quite helpful and responsive. I'd be glad if you could let me know the result of your research and I will update the question accordingly.